# How to know the total number of extras count that pass from previous activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to check how much intent extras is coming from Activity? for example:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
float i = intent.getFloatExtra("calculated", calculated);
float j = intent.getFloatExtra("calculated2", calculated2);

r1.setText(String.valueOf(i));
r2.setText(String.valueOf(j));
```

I know two extras are sending from one activity, can I use if else statements to check if there are more than 2 intent extras are coming to the new activity?

Comment: have you solved ?

Comment: getting intent extras of every values and made some conditions for all values if transferring 3 values to next activity or more than 3.... :D

        if (k != 0) {
            r3.setText(String.valueOf("Gauge   " + g3 + "     Weight Calculated   " + k));
        }
        if (l != 0) {
            r4.setText(String.valueOf("Gauge   " + g4 + "     Weight Calculated   " + l));
        }

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this in the next activity

```
String i = getIntent().getExtras().getString("calculated");
.....

    if(calculated!=null)
    {
      // write your logic here
    }
    else if (...){}
    .....
```

---

To know the extras count that pass from previous activity

```
 int num=getIntent().getExtras().size();
 Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"The total is "+num+" ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**.size() will return the total extras count.**

Comment: use  `Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();`